# Proving that an operator $T$ on a Hilbert space is compact

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $T:H \to H$ be a bounded linear operator and $T^{*}$ be the Hilbert Adjoint operator of $T$. Show that $T$ is compact if and only if $T^{*}T$ is compact.

My attempt:

Suppose first that $T$ is compact. The Hilbert Adjoint operator of $T$ is bounded therefore $T^{*}T$ is compact.

How can i proceed with the converse part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f = \text{w}-\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$. So we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \| T^* T (f_n-f)\|=0$ because $T^*T$ is compact. Also, we know that sequence $\{f_n-f\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded, so we have 
\begin{align*}\lim_{n \to \infty} \|T(f_n-f)\|^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle T^*T (f_n-f),f_n-f\rangle \leqslant \limsup_{n \to\infty} \|T^*T(f_n-f)\|\|f_n-f\| = 0,
\end{align*}
that is, $\text{s}-\lim_{n \to \infty} Tf_n = Tf$. So, $T$ is compact.

Comment: @johny No. That is just arbitrary sequence of elements of our Hilbert space which is weakly convergent. I used that bounded operator is compact iff operator maps weakly convergent sequences into strongly convergent sequences.

Comment: Thanks,I just had to review the definition of weak convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an outline of a proof in the direction you seek; you should be able to fill is the details:

Suppose $T^* T$ is compact.

1. Show that $\sqrt{ T^* T}$ is compact.
2. Use the Polar Decomposition to write $ T = U \sqrt{T^* T} $ for some
   partial isometry $U$.
3. Conclude that $T$ is compact.